# JCE 2.8.3 error: "The server returned an invalid JSON response"

Tags: joomla, joomla-content-editor

Recently I have updated the JCE editor from 2.8.2 to 2.8.3.

When I try to upload content from the JCE file browser, it is throwing an error saying:

> The server returned an invalid JSON response.

Seems the file is getting uploaded but the error is been thrown. Everything was working fine in the previous version 2.8.2.

Comment: Please always post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links will help you:

[Invalid JSON response in JCE File Browser (Joomla - StackExchange)](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/invalid-json-response-in-jce-file-browser)

[The server returned an invalid JSON response. (JCE Forums)](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum/95270-the-server-returned-an-invalid-json-response-6)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Recently the JCE has released a new version. Seems they have fixed the issue in the recent version.